# Iterating a function through different columns of a data.frame matching a pattern in the column names

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I want to iterate a function through different columns (with a common pattern in the column names) of a data.frame. 
for subsetting the data.frame I use this code that works:

```
df[,grep("abc", colnames(df))]
```

but I don't know how to apply my function f(x) to all the columns that match this pattern, either using a for loop or lapply function.

the function I'm using is:

```
compress= function(x) {
  aggregate(df[,x,drop=FALSE],
        list(hour = with(df,paste(dates(Time),
                                         sprintf("%d:00:00",hours(Time))))),
        sum,na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

where df (the data frame) and Time could be set as variables themselves but for the moment I don't need to do it.

Thanks
Giulia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've basically got it. Just use `apply` on the columns of your subsetted data to `apply` function `f` over columns (the `2` in the second argument of `apply` indicates columns, as opposed to `1` which indicates to `apply` over rows):

```
apply( df[,grep("abc", colnames(df))] , 2 , f )
```

Or if you don't want to coerce your `df` to a `matrix` (which will happen with `apply`) you can use `lapply` as you suggest in much the same manner...

```
lapply( df[,grep("abc", colnames(df))] , f )
```

The return value from `lapply` will be a list, with one element for each column. You can turn this back into a `data.frame` by wrapping the `lapply` call with a `data.frame`, e.g. `data.frame( lapply(...) )`

### Example

```
# This function just multiplies its argument by 2
f <- function(x) x * 2

df <- data.frame( AB = runif(5) , AC = runif(5) , BB = runif(5) )


apply( df[,grep("A", colnames(df))] , 2 , f )
#            AB        AC
#[1,] 0.4130628 1.3302304
#[2,] 0.2550633 0.1896813
#[3,] 1.5066157 0.7679393
#[4,] 1.7900907 0.5487673
#[5,] 0.7489256 1.6292801


data.frame( lapply( df[,grep("A", colnames(df))] , f ) )
#         AB        AC
#1 0.4130628 1.3302304
#2 0.2550633 0.1896813
#3 1.5066157 0.7679393
#4 1.7900907 0.5487673
#5 0.7489256 1.6292801

# Note the important difference between the two methods...
class( data.frame( lapply( df[,grep("A", colnames(df))] , f ) ) )
#[1] "data.frame"
class( apply( df[,grep("A", colnames(df))] , 2 , f ) )
#[1] "matrix"
```

#### Second edit

For the example function you want to run, it might be easier to rewrite it as a function that takes the `df` as input and a vector of column names that you want to operate on. In this example the function returns a list, with each element of that list containing an aggregated `data.frame`:

```
compress= function( df , x ) {
  lapply( x , function(x){
  aggregate(df[,x,drop=FALSE],
        list(hour = with(df,paste(dates(Time),
                                         sprintf("%d:00:00",hours(Time))))),
        sum,na.rm=TRUE)
    }
  )
}
```

To run the function you then just call it, passing it the data.frame and a vector of colnames...

```
compress( df , names(df)[ grep("abc", names(df) ) ] )
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, but there's still a little conceptual step that I don't understand:

I defined my function so that its only variable is the name of the column, that should be a character. Is the first argument of lapply specifying the variable on which it should apply the function?

Comment: @user2683963 you are welcome. Yes, the first argument of `lapply` is the variable to apply the function on. I would change your function so it operates on a column object. Why don't you add your function code above, it might be easiest to edit it...

Comment: @user2683963 I've added an edit to the answer which may be of help